# flow nested object values not accesible

Tags: reactjs, flowtype

I'm trying to access deeply nested values from an object but i'm getting the following error in flow:

`Property cannot be accessed on property 'author' of unknown type`

```
type ARTICLE_TYPE = {
  id: number,
  authorId: number,
  type: 'article' | 'video' | 'audio' | 'perspective',
  title: string,
  preview: string,
  imageUrl: ?string,
  date: string,
}

type AUTHOR_TYPE = {
  company: string,
  id: number,
  name: string,
  profileImage: string
}

type TileProps = {
  ...ARTICLE_TYPE,
  ...{
    author: AUTHOR_TYPE,
  },
  imageAspectRatio: string
}
```

I suspect it might be something to do with the way i'm defining the type but it seems ok to me:

Relevant testable code is [Here](https://flow.org/try/#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)

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you don't use spread operators with flow types, rather use type concatenation.

```
type TileProps = ARTICLE_TYPE & {
  author: AUTHOR_TYPE,
  imageAspectRatio: string
}
```

Make life easy on yourself and those who read your code after you.